# Ubuntu 23.10 Can't Print to Brother HL-L2370DW Using IPP Because of Inability to Resolve Printer Hostname

Tags: printing

I installed the Brother HL-L2370DW printer driver on a clean installation of Ubuntu 23.10 and chose the IPP protocol using Brother's "driver installer." (I have confirmed the Brother HL-L2370DW supports IPP in addition to AppSocket and LPD printing protocols.)

Logged into localhost:631/printers and clicked "Administration" and entered my computer's name and password and I successfully gained entrance to the CUPS administrator portal.

Clicked on the "print test page" button after noting the printer appeared to be "ready" and appeared to be correctly listed.

After clicking the "print test page" button, I waited for about three minutes as I observed a message indicating the print job was "processing."

Suddenly, one test page printed, which was encouraging, but odd in the sense that three minutes had elapsed after the button click before the page actually printed.

But since it took so long to get that test page to print, I decided to try again.

This time, I observed that the print job was again "processing." (And, after waiting several minutes, I noted nothing further happened; no test page printed.)

I finally noted a message indicating that the CUPS test page process was "temporarily unable to resolve the hostname" of the printer.

I use this Brother HL-L2370DW laser printer successfully with more than one iOS device (iPads and an iPhone) -- in addition to four Ubuntu 23.10 computers. Only the iOS devices can print to this printer successfully. All four Ubuntu 23.10 computers fail.

- CUPS can see the printer, but is somehow unable to resolve the hostname

So, I next chose the "modify" option to choose the AppSocket method instead. I typed the URI something like this: socket://(ip number) of the printer. That worked!

In addition, I also chose the "modify" option to choose the LPD method. URI was done in the same way: LPD://(ip number)/ of the printer and that also worked!

For whatever reason, however, the IPP method doesn't seem to want to work reliably due to inability of CUPS to resolve the hostname alias of the printer. The "DNNSD" URI is a long string that includes the model number and the so-called "node name" of the printer and it is this "node name" (which ends with .local) that apparently can't seem to be successfully resolved for completion of the print job.

How might I use the IPP printing protocol and successfully resolve the hostname of the print during test prints? I understand IPP is more secure than AppSocket and LPD.

Comment: I use the router settings to assign a fixed IP address to the printer, then you can just use that numerical IP in the IPP setting, no resolution needed.